# How to test heading of a react component using jest?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme, web-component-tester

I have a simple component which includes two buttons and the heading field. So far I tested button clicks but I want to test heading text field in the `<h3>` tag.

My component

```
class Popup extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="popupOuter">
                <div className="popupInner text-center">
                    <br/>
                    <h3>{this.props.config.text}</h3>
                    <br/>
                    <div>
                    <Button type='NoButton' value={'No'} onClick={this.props.config.back} />
                    <Button type = 'YesButton' value={'Yes'} onClick={this.props.config.next}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

My test

```
 test('Text test ', ()=>{
        const component = shallow(
            <Popup config={config}/>
        );
        expect(component.find('h3')).toEqual("h3");
    });
```

My test fails with

**Error: expect(received).toEqual(expected) // deep equality
Expected: "h3"
Received: {}**

What went wrong?
Explanation pls?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[.find(selector) => ShallowWrapper](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/find.html#findselector--shallowwrapper) returns shallow wrapper, obviously, the shallow wrapper is not equal to the string `h3`. If you want to get the text of this `h3` shallow wrapper, you need to call [.text() => String](https://enzymejs.github.io/enzyme/docs/api/ShallowWrapper/text.html#text--string) on the shallow wrapper.

E.g.

`index.tsx`:

```js
import React from 'react';
const Button = (props) => <button></button>;
export class Popup extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="popupOuter">
        <div className="popupInner text-center">
          <br />
          <h3>{this.props.config.text}</h3>
          <br />
          <div>
            <Button type="NoButton" value={'No'} onClick={this.props.config.back} />
            <Button type="YesButton" value={'Yes'} onClick={this.props.config.next} />
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```js
import { Popup } from './';
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';

describe('60759790', () => {
  it('should render text for h3', () => {
    const mProps = { config: { text: 'h3' } };
    const wrapper = shallow(<Popup {...mProps}></Popup>);
    expect(wrapper.find('h3').text()).toEqual('h3');
  });
});
```

unit test results:

```sh
 PASS  stackoverflow/60759790/index.test.jsx (8.126s)
  60759790
    ✓ should render text for h3 (10ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.418s
```